# optimizer hints within procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have been using hints to speed up my queries. 
but I noticed that the gains in run time disappear if the optimizer hints are within a procedure, example :

`execute immediate ' create table my_table as 
select 
 /*+ APPEND full(A) parallel (A,8)  full(B) parallel (B,64)  */
a.column1 .... '`

is this behavior normal ?
is there special syntax I should use ?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but the APPEND hint will only help with INSERTs.  If you want to create the table with direct path writes you should use the NOLOGGING keyword, and you'll likely want to run an `alter table my_table logging;` after the statement is complete.  Also, I recommend using statement level parallelism instead of object level parallelism.  Simply use `/*+ parallel(64) */` to make the whole statement run with a DOP of 64.  Finally, you'll also probably want to create the table with the `parallel` setting, and then alter it to `noparallel` afterwards.

Comment: This example is non-sense. CTAS allways use direct path write. You can remove it and nothing will change. I ment - remove APPEND hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the manuals hints are supported,  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#LNPLS864 , however the query you posted is dynamic SQL rather than static and that might be the issue.  Have you tried creating the table first then using Insert/Select instead.  A CTAS is DDL and the CBO rules on how queries can be transformed are more restrictive for DDL than DML and this is another potential cause of what your are seeing.